# PHP loop not performing as it should

Tags: php, mysql, loops, where-clause

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE data = '$userinput'";
 $row = mysql_query($query);

   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($row))
    {
         echo $row['data'];
    }
```

Ok So my questions are:

1. What exactly does mysql_fetch_array return?
2. AND if my WHERE clause finds multiple matches, shouldn't the loop execute numerous times?

I am running a program and I can only get the first result to print

Comment: u can always use var_dump on variables to see exactly what they are (u better use it, is it one of the most common tools in the debug box of a php developer)

Comment: OK thanks, I am just starting to learn PHP so the sql functions are a bit tricky

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php rtm

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Use "PHP Designer" editor, there's a built-in help for every PHP function.

Comment: So does it return a 1-D array with each call, then increment the pointer inside the function, to return another 1-D array?

Comment: @Vlad yes and it will do that until it reaches the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overwriting `$row`. Instead use a different variable for the query result.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE data = '$userinput'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['data'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I shouldve caught that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `mysql_fetch_assoc($row)`

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the same variable as the index and the loop variable.

```
$row = mysql_query

while( $row = ...
```

Replace the first `$row` with `$result`

Comment: Thanks. I didn't even notice.